# Can Rural Postman Problem with arbitrary start and end be reduced to Rural Postman Problem with single depot node?

Tags: graph-traversal, weighted-graphs, eulerian-paths

Can Rural Postman Problem with arbitrary start and end be reduced to Rural Postman Problem with single depot node?

The rural postman problem is:

*Given a weighted MultiDiGraph $G=(V,E)$, a subset of edges $A$ must be traversed.  The path must start and end at the depot node.  Find the shortest of all such paths.*

I'm wondering if a similar problem can be reduced to the above problem:

*Given a weighted MultiDiGraph $G=(V,E)$, a subset of edges $A$ must be traversed.  The path can start at arbitrary $s$ and end at arbitrary $t$.  Find the shortest of all such paths.*

I've explored a few reductions, similar to the common reduction used for max flow problems, by creating an artificial $s,t$, and connecting all arcs.  But, I'm not able to determine a proper reduction, nor a meaningful relationship between these two problems.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

edit: ("arbitrary" meaning start and end are not given.  However if a solution can be found if start and end are given, that might give us some useful insight.)

Answer (score 1):

Let the *rural postman problem without depot node* be denoted by $\textrm{RND}$
and the *rural postman problem with depot node* be denoted by $\textrm{RD}$.

Let $G = (V,E,w)$ be a positive weighted graph instance of $\textrm{RND}$. Add a new vertex $d$ to the graph. Add directed edges $(s,v)$ and $(v,s)$ for each vertex $v \in V$. Assign weight $W$ to each of these new edges such that $W = |E| \cdot \sum_{e \in E} w_e$, where $\sum_{e \in E} w_e$ the sum of weights of all edges in $G$. Let this new graph be $G'$ which is an instance of $\textrm{RD}$ with depot node $d$.

Then, the following claim holds:

*Claim:*  For $L < W$, there exists a feasible path of cost at most $L$ in $G$ for $\textrm{RND}$ if and only if there exists a feasible path of cost at most $L + 2W$ in $G'$ for $\textrm{RD}$.

*Proof:* ($\to$) Let $p = (v_1,\dotsc,v_k)$ be a feasible path of cost at most $L$ in $G$ for $\textrm{RND}$. Let the new path be $p' =: (d,v_1,\dotsc,v_k,d)$. This is a feasible path in $G'$ for $\textrm{RD}$. The cost of this path is at most $L + 2W$.

($\gets$) Let $p' = (d,v_1,\dotsc,v_k,d)$ be a feasible path of cost at most $L + 2W$ in $G'$ for $\textrm{RD}$. Note that any $v_i \neq d$; otherwise the cost of the path will be at least $3W$ which contradicts that the $L < W$. Therefore the subpath $p =: (v_1,\dotsc,v_k)$ lies completely inside $G$. The path $p$ is a feasible path in $G$ for $\textrm{RND}$. And, $p$ has cost at most $L$.

This proves the claim.

---

Note that I assumed that $L < W$, since for $L \geq W$, the problem can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but this is awesome.  So, by solving RND we are able to obtain an *upper bound* on the solution to RD?   Or can we obtain an optimal solution?

Comment: Also - when you refer to $L \ge W$ as being solvable in polynomial time, what canonical problem are you referring to, if there is one?

Comment: @somewhere Hi. I will reply to it in sometime.

Comment: Thanks, I'd appreciate that.  I'll also think about it myself.

Comment: why can't we do the following to reduce $RND$ to solving $RD$:  Original graph is $G$.  Add a depot node.  Connect depot node to all vertices, and give the new arcs cost =0.  Call this new graph $G'$.  By solving $RD$ in $G'$, it should give the optimal solution to $RND$ in $G$, right?